# arahow possible to check my facebook end points with older version (v4.0) via graph api explorer?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebooksdk.net

Suddenly one day my facebook app sdk was removed by hacker and I forced to create a new one by last week.Now my problem is that I couldn't able to check facebook end points via graph api explorer with version v4.0.It always showing v8.0.I have used v4.0 in old deleted app and called all end points with v4.0. So *how possible to check my facebook end points with v4.0 via graph api explorer?*

Comment: You can not use an API version lower than what was the current API version at the time you created your app id.